# UPI Intent in iOS - stuck

Tags: ios, android-intent, payment-gateway, upi, cashfree

I'm trying to integrate UPI intent in webview for my ecommerce app with Cashfree Payments. While the Android device does not have problem in switching back to my app from the Gpay or any PSP app the same does not work with iOS. After being taken to payment app and completing the payment, it stays there without coming back automatically. Tested with multiple devices but no use. Any suggestions would help. Thanks

Tried: multiple devices with iOS 15 and 16
Expected: TO switch back to my app after payment completing instead of me doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

The redirection will not happen on it's own as there is a complete navigation to PSP app and we have to come back to caller app manually. That's the expected behaviour

Answer (score 1):

As per the behaviour of iOS platform, the redirections from PSP apps to the primary app is not allow automatically (App switching) but the forward is supported.

This is not with any particular PSP app but global. Even Google's G-Pay Documentation has it mentioned.
[**Screenshot from Gpay**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHZXO.png)
https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/ios/in-app-payments

Whereas in Android this is not the case and both TO&FRO switching is allowed between User app and PSP App.